# windows terminal can't find my font that i just download

Tags: javascript, terminal, fonts

I'm about to start to use the Windows terminal. and I wanted to change my whole set of it. so I tried to change the font and downloaded it. but here's the question. although in control penal, there was the font that I downloaded and after searching for my problem, I used the "downloading for every user" function. but it didn't work. my terminal can't find my agave NF Nerd font..

```
"profiles": 
    {
        "defaults": 
        {
            "colorScheme": "One Half Dark",
            "font": 
            {
                "face":  "agave NF"
            },
            "opacity": 70,
            "useAcrylic": true
        },
    }
```

here's the code that I tried to put in the profiles defaults in js file of the Windows terminal.

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue if I installed the font for the logged in user only, i.e. $Env:UserProfile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts.

It worked when installed for all users i.e. right-click, more options, install for all users. See discussion at https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/12587.

Answer (score 1):

I know its a meme but restarting the Terminal worked for me.

The steps I took were:

1. Follow the steps on [Nerd Font Webinstall](https://webinstall.dev/nerdfont/) depending on your system
2. Open the settings on the Windows Terminal
3. Open the settings JSON file (located on the bottom left)
4. Add the following snippet under the defult section of your profile (as listed above in the question)
   `"font":{"face":"<font name>"},`
   or
   `"fontFace":"<font name>"`
5. Restart the Windows Terminal

I hope this helps anyone else running into this.

Comment: this works as one time solution, but on win11 after OS restart starting terminal shows `Unable to find the selected font ...`